# PHP Preg_march_all searching mulitple items with order not important

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to match 2 results in a single string, both need to exist for something to be returned but the order in which they are in the string is not important.

```
 $row = '[one]This[/one][two]That[/two]';
 preg_match_all('#(\[one\](.*?)\[/one\])(\[two\](.*?)\[/two\])#', $row, $result_match);
```

If $row was instead.
     $row = '[two]That[/two][one]This[/one]';

is it possible for the preg_match_all to find the results anyway.

I need to capture THAT and THIS and know if it is inside one or two.  Capture either both one and two or only capturing a single of the one or two would tell me which one the text was inside.

Update:

The final result I settled on is:

```
#[(?!\1)((?:one|two))](.*?)[\/\1]#
```

Users after this new feature released now want to be able to nest the commands.  I have tried changing ?:one|two to ?!.one|two to use negative look forward to match the final result in the string.

They want to be able to do this:

```
[one]This[one]This Again[/one][two]That Again[/two][/one][two]That[/two]
```

The desired capture would be

```
This[one]This Again[/one][two]That Again[/two]
```

And

```
[two]That[/two]
```

Update 2:

This is the full scope of what I am trying to do.

```
[run][one]This[/one][two]That[/two][/run]
[run][one]This 2[/one][two]That 2[/two][/run]
[run][one]IF THIS RESULT DO THIS [run][one]This[/one][two]That[/two][/run][/one][two]IF THIS RESULT DO THAT [run][one]This[/one][two]That[/two][/run][/two][/run]
```

The users do this all in one post and they want to be able to do nested runs. 
The desired results would be..

```
[one]This[/one][two]That[/two]
[one]This 2[/one][two]That 2[/two]
[one]IF THIS RESULT DO THIS [run][one]This[/one][two]That[/two][/run][/one][two]IF THIS RESULT DO THAT [run][one]This[/one][two]That[/two][/run][/two]
```

I can foreach the results to handle nested runs.  Is this even possible?

Comment: If you look above, it captures both, separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead, capture group and back-reference:

```
~(?:.*?\[(?!\1)([12])\].*?\[/\1\]){2}~
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/MDrsEG/1)

**Regex Description:**

- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `.*?`: Match 0 or more characters (non-greedy)
  - `\[`: Match `[`
  - `(?!\1)`: Assert that we don't have text same as back-reference `\1` ahead
  - `([12])`: Match `1` or `2` and capture in group #1
  - `\]`: Match `]`
  - `.*?`: Match 0 or more characters (non-greedy)
  - `\[`: Match `[`
  - `/\1`: Using back-reference, match same text as what we have in capture group #1
  - `\]`: Match `]`
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `{2}`: Match 2 instances of above non-capture group

---

**Update 2:**

After your update above regex won't work anymore as you want to capture text between the tags. You may use: this regex:

```
~(?|\[one\](.*?)\[/one\].*?\[two\](.*?)\[/two\]|\[two\](.*?)\[/two\].*?\[one\](.*?)\[/one\])~
```

Your captured groups are available in #1 and #2.

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/MDrsEG/5)

---

**Update 3:**

Based on recent conversation you may use this recursive regex to match bbcode data between outermost `[run]` and `[/run]` tags:

```
$re = '~\[(run)] ( (?: (?: (?! \[/?\1] ) . )* | (?R) )* ) \[/\1]~sx';
```

[Read more about recursive patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php)

[RegEx Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/3an3vc/12)

Comment: You are absolutely amazing at Regex (but I just found out you wrote a book on the subject)  The problem has only become more complex, but I am hoping you can help me, after putting it all together I just break it further.

Comment: You are outstanding, If you make a regex for php or javascript please let me know, I will get a copy.

Comment: Sure, I will definitely let you know once I publish something on PHP or Javascript. btw did this regex finally work for you?

Comment: 100%.  Now I just have to get the php parts working and with some luck everything should be great.  I use preg_match_all and preg_replace and the replace is going to he fun, but I'll get there.  Thank you very much for your help.  If in the future (which is very rarely) I need help with regex, I will absolutely seek you out.  Normally, I only do regex for SEO and I am good enough at it to handle all of that.  But for more advanced things like this, I do not have anywhere near your skill.

Comment: I thought it already had been, I am sorry, Anubhava.  (I also left you an amazon review to help you out)

Comment: Thank you so much for the review., That really helps a lot, much appreciated.

Comment: We've all got to help each other, that's what life's all about, no one gets anywhere alone.    I am sorry to keep asking, you had already told me the answer to this problem, but I am having a problem finding it.   https://regex101.com/r/3an3vc/7  I need the one and two to also match the last instance like the runs are in order to have the code loop back though to handle nesting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169370/discussion-between-anubhava-and-iscariot).